# Adding CSS selector in javascript

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a nav-bar which has `display:none` by default. When a user clicks on a hamburger icon at the top-right corner, I want to display it. What I've done is,

```html
   <nav id="navigation-bar">
      ....
   </nav>
```

Javascript:

```js
 const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu-cta"), //the menu icon
       navBar = document.getElementById("navigation-bar");
    

 menuBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
         navBar.classList.add('show-btn');
     });
```

In my css, the below style is not working

```css
.show-btn{
   display:block
}
```

But when I add nav. in front of it, it works

```css
nav.show-btn{
   display:block
}
```

ps: I'm using sass

Comment: Check how [specifity in CSS works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) , something is overriding your `display: block` style

Comment: You can also try to remove the id from the `<nav>` element. In JS you can change: `navBar = document.getElementById("navigation-bar");` to: `navBar = document.querySelector("nav");`. An `id` has an higher specificity weight then a `class`

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your nav tag

So that your Code should look like this

```js
 const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu-cta"), //the menu icon
       navBar = document.getElementById("navigation-bar");
    

 menuBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
         navBar.classList.add('show-btn');
 });
```

```css
.navbar{
  display:none;
}

.show-btn{
   display:block
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation-bar" class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

<button id="menu-cta">btn</button>
```

please don't add css to #navigation-bar{} otherwise it will have the highest specificty.
You can learn more here
[CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Another route is to use [toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) so the user can open and close your navigation.

```js
 const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menu-cta"), //the menu icon
      navBar = document.getElementById("navigation-bar");
    

 menuBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
      navBar.classList.toggle('hide');
 });
```

```css
.hide {
   display: none
}
```

```html
<button id="menu-cta">...</button>

<nav id="navigation-bar" class="hide">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```